# text-indent sem funcionar no Edge em um elemento do tipo select

Tags: layout, navegador-de-internet, html-select

Apliquei um text-indent em um select, esta funcionando em todos os navegadores atuais menos no Edge. Alguem ja passou por esse problema? alguma solução?

Segue o codigo:

```
.form-control select{
    width: 22.4%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    text-indent: 0.532em;
    border: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.188em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.188em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
```

}

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Opa @David, tudo bem? coloquei o código como você sugeriu.